# What does modular inversion mean?

Tags: implementation, terminology, number-theory, voting

I'm trying to implement an e-voting algorithm, which is described at the paper "Internet Voting Protocol Based on Improved Implicit Security" by Abhishek Parakh & Subhash Kak.

At the Example 1 described in the paper where we have m1=85, at the step 2 it says

"2. Choose randomly and uniformly a number r1 = 101
and compute r2 = m1*(r1)^-1 = 85*(101)^-1=85*28=67mod257"

How is this possible? I mean how can 101^-1 be 28?

Comment: This *really* should have gone to Math.SE instead, it's purely a number-theoretical computation problem. Its relation to cryptography is incidental at best and is unlikely to ever help someone who's specifically studying the cited paper.

Comment: If you want help implementing something from a paper, please add a link to the paper itself (pdf is good; something behind a paywall is not good).

Comment: The wikipedia article is decent: [Modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that the result says 67 **mod 257**.
All calculations here are being done [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) 257. So, $101^{-1}$ is actually the [modular inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of $101 \bmod 257$, which is 28. Similarly, $85 \cdot 28$ is also done modulo 257.